# Mustache.js throwing error on rendering smaller templates in Android mobile

Tags: android, mustache

This is the template i'm trying to render.

```
<div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#/account" class="fill-div">View Balance</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#/transactions" class="fill-div">View Transaction History</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't have any json component. My Mustache code to render is very simple.

```
function getTemplate(name) {
    $.get("../templates/" + name, function (template) {
      try {
        html = Mustache.render(template, true);
        $('#place_holder').html(html);
      }catch(ex){
        alert(ex);
      }
    });
}
```

This code works perfectly fine in the browser. But when i pack it using phonegap and when i try running it in Android mobile im getting an error as below.

[image]

Any Hint of what might be wrong? Happy to provide more details if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the jQuery get request.

$.get was returning an object[document] in the emulators and in mobile device. So added "text" to $.get and it fixed the problem.

```
 $.get("../templates/" + name, function (template) {
        html = Mustache.render(template, true);
        $('#place_holder').html(html);
    }, "text");
```